# How to wait after a database value then continue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, paypal

I got an e-commerce website that uses the PayPal Adaptive Payment. The Adaptive Payment requests a PayKey to be generated from PayPal to create an invoice. The delay to get the PayKey is long enough so I had the idea to put the code in a separate thread, while the user answer some other questions before being redirected to PayPal, see code below:

```
    await Task.Run<Task>(async () =>
    {
        var payResponse = await _payPalApplicationService.ProceedWithPayPal(currentEvent.Id, order.InvoiceId, order.TrackingId, owners.Single(), vModel.TotalPrice, vModel.DeliveryPriceTotal, orderToAdd.TotalTaxes, orderToAdd.SalesRate + orderToAdd.SalesRateTaxes, vModel.SKUViewModels, _payPalApplicationService.PayPalCore._serviceEndPointUrl);
        order.PayKey = payResponse.payKey;

        _orderService.Update(order);
        await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
```

The problem I got is some users can go quick enough so the PayKey has not been generated before being redirected to PayPal.

Did you know anything I can do to make sure I got the PayKey before redirect the users to PayPal? The thread task is done in a different controller action than the one with the redirection.

Thank you

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It arguably violates an MVC principle of statelessness but a really simple solution would be to store the PayKey retrieval task against the session.

So change the above code to:

```
Session["PaypalTask"] = await Task.Run<Task>(async () =>
{
    var payResponse = await _payPalApplicationService.ProceedWithPayPal(currentEvent.Id, order.InvoiceId, order.TrackingId, owners.Single(), vModel.TotalPrice, vModel.DeliveryPriceTotal, orderToAdd.TotalTaxes, orderToAdd.SalesRate + orderToAdd.SalesRateTaxes, vModel.SKUViewModels, _payPalApplicationService.PayPalCore._serviceEndPointUrl);
    order.PayKey = payResponse.payKey;

    _orderService.Update(order);
    await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

Then you can later retrieve the task in your other controller and `await` it there. If it has already completed exectution will just continue immeadiately, else it will wait for it to complete before continuing.

Something like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var payPalTask = Session["PaypalTask"] as Task;

    await payPalTask;

    return RedirectToAction("CompltedPayment");
}
```

Of course, you may also want to consider error handling etc.

UPDATE

I should mention that the above method stores session state *in memory*. There are some complications if your application uses multiple servers where you may want to research sticky sessions, or some kind of distributed cache like redis.

UPDATE2:

I have published a demo mocking out the async method with a simple `Task.Delay` to [here](https://github.com/stewart-r/SessionDemo). If you build this web app then navigate to /InitiatePp it will start the request. Then /PpResult/Result will give the status of the running task and /PpResult/Wait will await completion of the task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the redirection is done no matter the task is complete or not. I tried payPalTask.Wait(); it didn't work either.

Comment: Hmmm. I tested it with a simple `Task.Delay` mocking out the asynchronous​ function. You are sure you're not doing `await` in the first function too?

Comment: Would you write your test in the answer please? I guess I miss something.

Comment: Yeah will do. I'll maybe jus

Comment: Sorry. Was going to say..   maybe just post the solution to github or something. On mobile just now tho (hence the mispost! :) ) so will need to be later

Comment: @DavidLétourneau My apologies David, I made a mistake above. Can Only apologise. you DO need to await the first task in the controller action that initiates the request. Thas really foolish of me, I had fixed it in my test. Sorry! I have updated the above with a link to a working demo